# Concat blobs / byte code of WebM video file and create new single file

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-processing

I need some advice. I'm making a SaaS application, in which I'm providing screen recording feature and to record screen

I'm using following approach:

- Records the clips of screen and save in S3 storage
- When the recording is completed I concat these clips as one using script that is on EC2

**How I am recording?** 
I'm using **MediaRecorder** to make clips. On event of data available i get the blobs of clip convert it into **Webm** and upload it to S3 bucket
Why I'm using clips to record instead of recording it as 1 is because videos can be quite long from 3 to 5 hours. due to this if I create a single clip it can take a lot of RAM to prevent use of extensive RAM I am making clips now until this it's working find although I'm not satisfied with this approach.

Now the problem I'm facing is in concatenation of clips. If I use AWS services they are way too much expensive.
Is there any way to create new video file by concatenating of clips using JS

If anyone has advice to change my "dividing video into clips" approach I'm all ears. If you have any advice to resolve my joining video issue I'll be very grateful.

I also tried using **ffmpeg-fluent** and it is taking quite a lot of time on my local machine.
I came up with solution that is to take buffers of clips and use JS script and concat them but issue is new file is just showing clip of single video

Comment: Ffmpeg with `-f concat` option shouldn't re-encode the video, so should be fast. E.g. as here: https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/496#issuecomment-203005754

Comment: @Shozab **(1)** How to do a correct **concat** (using Javascript) will depend on the **codec** of the video (_eg:_ h.264? VP9?). Also the container **format** (_eg:_ MP4? WebM?) which is setup differently. Either you join frames at codec level or else just edit the metadata (to account for all joined frames) at container level... **(2)** You have to edit the metadata of the first file (which acts as container for all the other frames). For example: MP4 has a **duration** which must change, and then the **size** for each metadata section will be changed by the sizes/position of extra frames etc

Comment: PS: See if there's anything (useful library) [on Github](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+concat+mp4+github)

Comment: @VC.One thanks for the advice. I'll surely look into this